# How do I get back to Pandaria from Draenor?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As the title states, how do I get there? I can't find a portal anywhere.

Answer (score 12):

Return to Orgrimmar or Stormwind (this can be done via a mage portal or any of the portals in Ashran). From there, if you go to the Pandaren area of the city you'll see a portal to Pandaria. Alternatively, you can have a Mage portal you directly to your Shrine. Some people prefer to set their Hearthstones to their Shrine as it contains a Portal to every major city and is somewhat annoying to get to otherwise.

Comment: Good advice regarding setting your Hearthstone to your factions Shrine.

Comment: Ashran also contains a portal to Shrine depending on your faction.